# Does animal include human?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, meaning, animals

In today's English the word "animal" can include or exclude humans, depending on context.
How about the word *animal* in classical Latin?
Does it include humans?
If not, is there a term that would cover human and other animals?
If *animal* means "something with *anima*", then humans should be included, but this argument feels insufficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Animal* is certainly applicable to men, both in classical literary usage and in prevalent philosophical discourse.

### Classical Literary Usage

1. Referring to man

   First, a few examples of *animal* being used to refer to men, all taken from the [Lewis & Short entry for *animal*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Danimal):

   > **animal hoc** prouidum, sagax, multiplex, acutum, memor, plenum rationis et consilii, **quem uocamus hominem**, praeclara quadam condicione generatum esse a supremo deo. (Cic. Leg. 1.22)

   and

   > **Sanctius his animal** mentisque capacius altae
   >   deerat adhuc et quod dominari in cetera posset.
   >   Natus homo est... (Ov. M. 1.76-78)
2. Distinguishing from man

   *Animal* can also be used to **distinguish from men**. In other words, it can be used just as the English word *animal*. One example:

   > Sed ea non ab hominibus modo petitur verum etiam ab animalibus... (Quint. 6, 3, 57)

### Philosophical Usage

A strong philosophical current defined man as belong to the genus *animal* and having the specific difference of being *rationale*. This goes back to Aristotle's definition of man as a "zoon logikon."

Thus, Quintillian:

> Itaque a genere perveniendum ad ultimam species: ut homo est animal non est satis, id enim genus est; mortale, etiamsi est species, cum aliis tamen communis finitio; rationale, nihil supererit ad demonstrandum id quod velis. (Quint. Inst. 5 10.56)

The medieval scholastics took and ran with this Aristotelian current. Aquinas provides a good example:

> Unde etiam in rebus humanis, si quaeratur, quis est iste? Respondetur, Socrates, quod nomen est suppositi, si autem quaeratur, quid est iste? Respondetur, animal rationale et mortale. (*Summa Theologiae* I Q. 31 a. 2 ad 4)

Comment: I had trouble quickly finding where Aristotle uses the term "zoon logikon." If anyone has that, I can add the reference.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! And I'm not just saying that because of the beer. Good quotations, too! I believe Aristotle mentioned the zoon logicon in his Metaphysica, but I don't know the exact place.

Comment: @Cerberus A bit late, but it turns out Aristotle doesn't really say it explicitly: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/42206/does-aristotle-ever-explicitly-refer-to-man-as-a-rational-animal

Comment: Ah, excellent! So it is a common misconception, although it's not extremely far from the truth.